# Automate Windows Server 2008/2012 patching

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-update

I primarily work as a software developer at my company. Recently, we had a new department created called CyberSecurity. They have implemented a responsibility that all developer is responsible to keep the test, staging, and production server patched and up to date + install any fixes recommended by an automated report they generate.

This task has now started to affect my working hours severely. Some regular updates are pushed to Windows update on servers but the update recommended in the security report is not part of them. They have selected vulnerabilities that may be recommended for one Win 2008 server but not for the other.

I need some way to help myself in this regards. Ideally, I was thinking If I can create a server-wise excel file with all KBs required to be installed from the report. Then, for each server, execute a script of a tool if already exist to attempt to install those KBs (download, if needed).

I'm not a server admin. This is new to me. Any automation or management help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I won't delve into how awesomely stupid I think this idea ist (theirs, not yours), but to try to help you we need more information. Do you get Windows updates from some server which preselects them? Or from the MS update servers? This should really be handled by either "CyberSecurity" (sic) themselves or you should be given the correct tools (like SCCM, WSUS, or some other automation / patching tool). There is some stuff you could try like https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wua_sdk/searching--downloading--and-installing-specific-updates

Comment: "It's now the responsibility of the customer to make sure the bank doesn't get robbed." - Yes, this is an awesomely stupid idea.